# Electrostatics - Ripping Tape off of a Table

Tags: electrostatics

I was doing an experiment at home.

I was ripping two pieces of tape off of a table and holding them close to each other. I found out that they repel each other.

I learned at school that it is the flimsier object that loses its electrons. In this case, it is the tape that loses it electrons.

I was wondering if it is true if it was the tape that was losing its electrons or if we simply don't know which was is losing electrons?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The tape holds onto the electrons -- the table loses them.

"Flimsy" objects don't lose the electrons.  The object which loses the electrons is the one with the lower electron affinity.  Electron affinities are [tabulated](https://www.alphalabinc.com/triboelectric-series/) on many sites.

By the way, you discovered a very important phenomena for those who assemble electronic parts.  Many electronic parts are sensitive to static electricity.  Those who work with such components must avoid things like tape because ripping off the tape generates charges which can destroy the sensitive electronics.  If you ever receive ESD training at a company, they will make a big deal about not using plain ol' tape.  They aren't kidding!  It's actually a big deal!